# Header disappearing and appearing again in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have created a fixed positioned header containing a logo and a navigation bar. When you scroll down the header should stay at the top of the screen.

In Firefox this works perfectly. Although in Chrome it behaves strangely, disappears and then appears again. I thought this could be a z-index issue but have not been able to resolve it.

I'm also not to sure as to which snippets of code I should show you guys as I have NO idea what is causing this! Some help / advice would be greatly appreciated!

Link to the test site here [HERE](http://tomfoolery.loudcrowd.co.za/)

I'm using Version 33.0.1750.154 of Chrome and I'm testing on desktop platform.

Comment: What version of Chrome? Also desktop, mobile or both?

Comment: there is no link 'HERE'

Comment: can you pls give link here

Comment: Version 33.0.1750.154 m on desktop.

Comment: Apologies, link added.

Comment: Do not link your website! Create a jsfiddle. `Why?` Because you're gonna fix your website soon (possibly based on correct answer) and your question will become unusable for other SO users. Downvoting this until you create a fiddle or at least post the code here. `Obey the rules of Stack Overflow please.`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: relative;` on `#page-content` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you. What caused the relative positioning of the container to do this?

Comment: A relative position makes absolute and fixed elements within this relative element dependent in it instead of the document.